# Using TeX with dropbox on multiple platforms: encoding issues

Tags: mac, linux, font-encodings

I use TeX on my laptop (OS X) and on my workstation (Linux RHEL 6) and I have issues with the encoding of some files where I use accents (mostly in authors names, but also because I'm French and I have some documents in French). I guess my issues is that I sometimes rely on the more flexible encoding on the Mac side to use accented characters directly like é instead of doing `{\'{e}}` for example. Then through Dropbox, or maybe because I then open these files on UNIX, these accents get mangled differently on both sides, and I obtain 2 different looking files on both sides. I'm pretty sure I could fix all this by using only the escape way but I might be able to do something more elegant (maybe I need to explicitly set the encoding both in the .`tex` file and in `vi`). I'm not sure what happens if I go to another editor then like TeXshop...

Do you have some pointers or a more elegant solution to my problem? Let me know if you need more information ! Thanks !

UPDATE: Thanks to some of the pointers given, I know a little bit more about the issues now. 
I created a small sample file to reproduce the issue. If I create it in TeXShop, it seems to work fine whereas the issue exists if I create the file with vim. Additionally, the `file --mime-encoding test.tex` yields different output depending on the way of creating the file:

```
$ file --mime-encoding test.tex 
test.tex: unknown-8bit
$ file --mime-encoding test2.tex 
test2.tex: utf-8
```

```
kheldar@shadowfax /Users/kheldar/Dropbox/Boulot/CV/csuros/2011
$ vi test.tex 
kheldar@shadowfax /Users/kheldar/Dropbox/Boulot/CV/csuros/2011
$ vi test2.tex 

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{Test encoding}
\maketitle

Test accents: é è ê ë

\begin{verbatim}
Test accents: é è ê ë
\end{verbatim}

Test accents: \'{e} \`{e} \"{e}

\begin{verbatim}
Test accents: \'{e} \`{e} \"{e}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Note that even with the TeXShop created file with utf-8, I don't see utf-8 in the status bar described by @Daniel. So it must be my `vimrc` right? Somehow I have other options that interfere with the `set filencoding` command. Any idea?

Comment: Check the default encoding in the preferences of TeXShop; they should be "Unicode UTF-8", as probably `vi` on the Unix side will be using that encoding.

Comment: Copying between platforms is usually fine provided the editors are set up correctly. Have you tried using a cross-platform editor where you can know that this is correct (for example TeXworks, which is native UTF-8 and cross-platform)?

Comment: To speed up the process, please provide us with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? Just put two files `linux.tex` and `mac.tex` created on the respective platform and with accented characters into the `Public` folder of your dropbox and post the links to them here.

Comment: @Daniel So the example files both work now, you can check them at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/167859/OSX_vim.tex and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/167859/LINUX_vim.tex

Comment: There might have been something weird with ~/.vimrc and I cleaned them up. The 2 remaining issues are that somehow my vim status line on the mac never displays the encoding while it does so on Linux. The other issue is how do I change the encoding of some older files (who are apparently in `latin1`, the previous OSX default I believe)? But I might be able to find that answer somewehere else. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: To get the actual buffer encoding independently from the statusline just do a `set enc`. To convert existing files there is the `iconv` program  (`iconv -cs -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 latin.tex > utf8.tex`, details available with `man iconv`. Another option is to load them into vim and then do a `set fenc=utf8` (whereas `enc` should remain `latin1`) and then write the buffer back to disk. Whenever `fenc` is different from `enc`, vim converts (using `iconv`, by the way) the buffer to `fenc` on write.

Comment: So the `set enc` doesn't work (`E519: option not supported`) and when I look at the help, I see that it only works if my vi was compiled with the `multi-byte` option. Could it be that my vi (which I believe is the default OS X one, version 7.3.3) was not compiled with that option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most important pieces of advice:

- Use `utf8` for the encoding of your documents (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`). In `vim` you set this encoding by `set filencoding=utf8`; depending on your shell's locale settings (`locale`) this might already be the default. In TexShop, you have to set the file encoding explicitly in the preferences.
- Refrain from using accented characters in your file names! MacOS's "special" interpretation of UTF8 in filenames (they are stored in decomposed form) causes all sorts of troubles.

For `vim` it is furthermore a good idea to define a status line that shows indicators for the actual text encoding and line-ending encoding (if you put the following lines into you `~/.vimrc` the file type, line ending and text encoding is shown on the right):

```
" show statusline
hi StatusLine ctermbg=black ctermfg=white guibg=black guifg=white gui=none
hi EMPH ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=black guibg=black guifg=yellow gui=none
set statusline=%F\ \|%c,%l:\ 0x%-02B\|%=\ \|%{strftime(\"%c\",getftime(expand(\"%:p\")))}\|\ %y\ %{&ff}\ %#EMPH#%{(&fenc==\"\"?&enc:&fenc)}
set ls=2
```

[image]

Thereby, you can quickly grasp if the encoding is right. If you google for "vim statusline" you will find a plethora of guides and tutorials on how to setup a good status line. Mine is still relatively simple.

Comment: I actually have all these set up but I still can't get it to work. I just typed an accented character in my tex file, closed the file and reopened (on OS X) and I got the mangled characters... One more piece of information, the output of the `file` command on my `tex` file: `LaTeX 2e document text`

Comment: @FrenchKheldar That seems a problem with the default encoding on TeXShop. Put the line `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8` when on the Unix side and try reopening in TeXShop

Comment: OK so I put your status line and I can see that the utf-8 tag doesn't appear. That means that despite what I have in my `~/.vimrc` and in the header of the `tex`, it is not taking it into account... Any clue as to what is happening? Thanks for your help...

Comment: It's 2011 and `XeTeX` and `LuaTeX` exist, which both can handle Unicode directly; there's no need to stick with `pdftex` and use `[utf8]{inputenc}` anymore.

Comment: @egreg It shows up fine in TeXShop but appears as `?` in vi in OS X and as `<8e>` in vi in UNIX.

Comment: I actually think the default encoding in TeXShop is still MacOS Roman, not UTF-8, although it's easy to set in the TeXShop preferences.  You need to restart TeXShop when if you change the default encoding.

Comment: @AlanMunn: You are correct, the default is MacOS Roman. Just happened to see this after formatting this mac and messing with all the settings.

Comment: @FrenchKheldar: _"OK so I put your status line and I can see that the utf-8 tag doesn't appear."_ What appears instead of if? It should give you the encoding your file actually has.

Comment: @Daniel That's the thing I see nothing after the `[vim] unix`. I'm updating the question with my new findings...